# Getting value of select option in react

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material UI](https://material-ui-next.com/api/select/) for my react app and am trying to get the value of a select form.

This works perfectly with the following code:

```
<select name="role" value={props.role} onChange={props.handleInputChange}>
            <option value="client">Client</option>
            <option value="worker">Worker</option>
          </select>
```

However, if I try to implement the exact same thing using Material UI

```
 <FormControl margin="dense" className={classes.textFieldSelect}>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="role" >Role</InputLabel>
            <Select
              value={props.role}
              onChange={props.handleInputChange}
              input={<Input id="role" />}
            >
              <MenuItem value="worker">Worker</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="client">Client</MenuItem>
            </Select>
 </FormControl>
```

Here's the code for handInput change in my parent component:

```
  handleInputChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({ currentUser: { ...this.state.currentUser, [name]: value } });
  }
```

The value of the select bar doesn't change when I click the menu items. However, the values do change in the TextField if I select a different role in the plain HTML element.

Any clues on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the current snippet, maybe if you show more code, for example : handleInputChange ?

Comment: I added that to the questions now. Funny thing is that it works fine with the plain HTML implementation of <select>

Comment: What about props.role ? Does that get updated in your parent component?

Comment: I just spent some time debugging it and it turns out that the reason it didn't work is because the e.target.name property is undefined when I click the <MenuItem>. I can fix this by passing in a specific name parameter when I call handleInputChange (e.g. handleInputChange('role')). Thanks for looking at it though!

Comment: So role was not getting updated. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent some time debugging it and it turns out that the reason it didn't work is because the e.target.name property is undefined when I click the . I can fix this by passing in a specific name parameter when I call handleInputChange (e.g. handleInputChange('role')). Thanks for looking at it though!